# Create report and upload to server for download

Tags: csv

I have a CSV file thats 300MB and has over 1/2 million entries. I want to run reports and make these reports available for download.

Here's the data structure:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
```

What I'd like to do is create a separate file that contains the top 50 rows when the file has been sorted by column B.

Comment: 1 time or is the process repeated? Eg. does the data change?  (open in excel, sort by column B copy 1st 50 rows paste into sheet 2 save sheet2 as your 2nd report...

Comment: Repeated on a daily basis & must be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to process your data, it supports the [indexing of CSV data](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV).

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) solves the problems associated with uploading, downloading and searching the data. It's performance is such that the index can be easily updated or built again from scratch.

## Example

### Install Solr

Read the documentation for how to install Solr. The following is a "kick-start" to make this demo work on Linux:

```
wget http://www.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.5.0/apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz
tar zxvf apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz
cd apache-solr-3.5.0/example
java -jar start.jar
```

Solr admin screen available on the following URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/
```

### Generate sample data

Wrote a groovy script to generate a sample CSV file.

```
new File("data.csv").withWriter { writer ->
    writer.println "id;A_s;B_i;C_s;D_s;E_s;F_s"

    for (i in 1..500000) {
        writer.println "${i};${i*10};${i*20};${i*30};${i*40};${i*50};${i*60}"
    }
}
```

Example

```
id;A_s;B_i;C_s;D_s;E_s;F_s
1;10;20;30;40;50;60
2;20;40;60;80;100;120
3;30;60;90;120;150;180
4;40;80;120;160;200;240
5;50;100;150;200;250;300
6;60;120;180;240;300;360
7;70;140;210;280;350;420
8;80;160;240;320;400;480
9;90;180;270;360;450;540
..
```

*Note:*

I performed no customisation to the "out of the box" Solr settings. This meant

- Default Solr configuration requires a unique **id** field
- Appending "_s" to the column name indicates string fields. See [dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) feature in Solr
- Loaded Column B as an integer (B_i) to enable numeric sorting

See the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) for details on how to write a custom schema.

### Load CSV file

The [Linux curl](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) command is used to load the **data.csv** file, by performing a HTTP post operation:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?separator=;&commit=true' -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' --data-binary @data.csv
```

**Note:**

- 500,000 rows of data loaded in approx 90 seconds
- Use **separator** parameter to indicate the data is not separated by the default ","
- Use **commit** parameter to indicate data is committed to index at the end.

### Query the data

The following query returns the top 50 rows sorted on column B

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&rows=50&sort=B_i+desc&fl=id,A_s,B_i,C_s,D_s,E_s,F_s&wt=csv
```

Output is CSV formatted:

```
id,A_s,B_i,C_s,D_s,E_s,F_s
500000,5000000,10000000,15000000,20000000,25000000,30000000
499999,4999990,9999980,14999970,19999960,24999950,29999940
499998,4999980,9999960,14999940,19999920,24999900,29999880
499997,4999970,9999940,14999910,19999880,24999850,29999820
499996,4999960,9999920,14999880,19999840,24999800,29999760
..
```

[REST parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters):

```
  |-------------------------------|------------------------------|
  | Rest parameter                | Description                  |                      
  |-------------------------------|------------------------------|
  | q=*:*                         | Everything.                  |
  | rows=50                       | Number of rows to output     |
  | sort=B_i+desc                 | descending order, sort on B_i|
  | fl=id,A_s,B_i,C_s,D_s,E_s,F_s | columns to include           |
  | wt=csv                        | CSV output                   |
  |-------------------------------|------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making one liners today, and Solr seems like overkill.  Here's one to solve your problem (assuming no header row):

```
sort -t\; -k2 < test.csv | head -50
```

Add -n if you need the second field sorted numerically instead of alphabetically.