# java- most memory /cpu efficient way of writing/appending/searching for text into/from CSV file

Tags: java, csv

There are many libraries for reading/writing/appending text from/into a csv file in java.

Which one is the most memory and CPU-efficient library for reading text from a csv file?

Also, I have a scenario in which text is appended into very large csv files- which library is most suitable for this purpose?

One major requirement is support for any type of charset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Smooks](http://www.smooks.org) is an extensible framework for building applications for processing XML and non XML
data (CSV, EDI, Java etc) using Java.

On this link there is an example on how to read a csv in java:
http://svn.codehaus.org/milyn/tags/Smooks_V1.2/smooks-examples/csv-to-java/

Answer (score 1):

I find  [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) extremely useful in providing a search capability for CSV data.

See following example:

[Create report and upload to server for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459619/create-report-and-upload-to-server-for-download/8462145#8462145)