# Making csv file to url

Tags: url, csv

I have a server and a domain name.I would like to upload a csv file to them so as to be able to see it as a url.For example if my domain is www.example.com if I type the adress www.example.com/file.csv to show me the contents of my file

Any ideas how I will be able to make my csv file as a url to my domain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you were asking, but if you want the user to be able to click the link for http://www.example.com/file.csv and have the contents of the file display in the browser instead of prompting for download, try adding a MIME type to your server for CSV as `text/plain`.

This works for, but I'm running IIS 7.  I don't know how effective it is on other web servers.

Comment: To be more precise I need to make it as a url feed so as to be able to use the module on Drupal Commerce Feeds https://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds that demands the csv file to be as a url feed and upload my csv to the website.as it is a csv file with product contents.So still is the way i should do it? that you mention? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about uploading your CSV files into a [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) index? The advantage of this alternative solution is that it would make your data searchable.

Data can be uploaded using simple HTTP POST operation. The Linux [curl](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) command could be used as follows:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?separator=;&commit=true' -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' --data-binary @data.csv
```

Here's a related answer with example implementation:

- [Create report and upload to server for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459619/create-report-and-upload-to-server-for-download/8462145#8462145)